# Running R script daily using crontab in OSX

Tags: r, macos, cron

I would like to set up a crontab that **runs the emailSender.R script daily at 5pm Monday to Friday.**

The script of emailSender.R is as follows:

```
library(rmarkdown)

rmarkdown::render("htmlmarkdown.Rmd")


library(gmailR)
gmailR::gmail(
  to =c("recipient@email.com"),
  subject = "Subject",
  message = "Message",
  username = "me@email.com",
  password = "password",
  attachment = "htmlmarkdown.html"
)
```

I then open up terminal to set up the crontab by first typing crontab -e.

Then a window pops up where I try to set up my cronjob using the following code.

```
0 17 * * * Rscript /Users/username/emailSender.R
```

Unfortunately, emailSender.R doesn't run as scheduled.

Would greatly appreciate any help on getting a crontab to schedule my R script

EDIT: After going back to my terminal and typing Rscript I am prompted:

```
-bash: Rscript: command not found
```

Perhaps I have to set Rscript in my PATH before cron can set-up the task. Unsure how to do that despite searching extensively.

Comment: Personally, I use a cron GUI (on Linux, it's called Scheduled tasks) to set up my cron jobs, and I have it run `bash r_script_runner.sh`. That file just has `#! /bin/bash` in the first line and `path/to/r_script.R`. This works fine.

Comment: thanks I tried using the cronnix GUI on OSX and couldn't get it to work either.

Comment: Press Escape to exit Insert mode then type `:wq` to write and quit.

Comment: Type `which Rscript` in Terminal to find where it is installed, then use that full path in your `crontab` rather than plain `Rscript`.

Comment: If you'd rather use a graphical editor to edit your crontab do this before running `crontab -e`... `export EDITOR=/Applications/TextEdit.app/Contents/MacOS/TextEdit`

Answer (score 2):

Try installing the cronR package.

Once you do this, you should be able to navigate to tools > Addins where you can execute the package. It will bring up a scheduler that will allow you to schedule a time for your script to run.

If you have permission issues, go to System preferences > security > Privacy. Click the 'full disk access' and grant RStudio / R access. This should allow you to schedule jobs to run in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the path of Rscript:

```
0 17 * * * /usr/local/bin/Rscript /Users/username/emailSender.R
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this code at the beggining:

```r
Sys.setenv(RSTUDIO_PANDOC="/usr/lib/rstudio-server/bin/pandoc")
```